# How to post a request when back online in Angular 2

Tags: angular, offline, offline-mode

I'm looking to create an application in Angular 2 that is online first but if the connection is lost and the user tries to submit the form, it will be cached and sent when the connection is restored.

I was looking at service workers but it seems like they are used for responding to requests from the client.

Not sure if it's relevant but I would be using node on the server.

Comment: you may wana look at pouch db.